# Mudar css pelo debugger do navegador

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Olá, iniciei em desenvolvimento web a pouco tempo, e estou querendo automatizar meu serviço, conseguir fazer ele mais rápido.

Antes para fazer alterações em css eu abria o arquivo css no `visual studio` fazia a alteração e ai eu recarregava a página, hoje eu melhorei um pouco, eu aperto f12 e vou fazendo as alterações pelo debugger, mas todas as vezes eu preciso copiar o código e ir la e colar no arquivo css no visual studio, como mostra a figura 1 e 2.

[FIGURA 1]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[FIGURA 2]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Existe alguma maneira de ao fazer alteração no css pelo debugger, ele altere automaticamente no visual studio??